# C’est à quel point courant de dire « Ça a été ? » à quelqu’un après un examen ?

Tags: langage-des-jeunes

Je crois que c'est utilisé comme équivalent de l'anglais « How was it? »  mais est-ce que c’est assez courant de dire ça ? Du moins chez les jeunes ?

Answer (score 6):

C'est assez courant (pas seulement chez les jeunes) et en particulier c'est assez habituel dans les restaurants à la fin du repas pour demander à quelqu'un s'il est satisfait du repas.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking rather "Did it go well?", "Did everything go well?", "Did you do okay/all right?", "Was it all right?", "Did you like it ?", "Are you satisfied?", "Did it work (well)?" … What form is equivalent depends on the context.

"How was it?" is  "Comment c'était ?".

It's current enough and anybody can say that, but numerous other possibilities are also available; the few instances given below belong to the standard language and are usable in the   context you mention;

Ça a marché ? — Ça s'est bien passé ? — c'était facile ? — Tu as réussi ? (T'as réussi ?) — Tu t'es bien débrouillé ? — Tu t'en es sorti ?

Young people have enough expressions for the need of putting across their ideas and they shouldn't reject these. Nevertheless, there must be ways to express the notion that'll be particular to school slang and suburban slang, but they are likely to be restricted to regional use, to particular schools (argot des polytechniciens for instance, and nobody in France really wants to learn how students say things in the  *Polytechniques* school).

ADDITION
Let's mention anyway a case of locution which in my opinion belongs to the rough language, as it is widespread in its usage and not particular to any one region; it is to be notice that it is labelled in the TLFi only as colloquial. It appeals necessarily to the young as it is for the least very informal, but it is not typically a locution associated to the young and has been in use for a long time; it's "**Ça gaze ?**"; in this locution the verb "gazer" is used impersonally and  only with « ça »; in recent years certain people, no doubt the young, have started using the verb as a fully conjugated verb (je gaze, tu gaze, il gaze, …) but that is rather extravagant. The addition of this expression is due to
user **hoplageiss**, who was able to think of it (see comments).

Comment: T'as gazé ? — Ça a gazé ? sont deux autres expressions fréquemment utilisées.

Comment: @hoplageiss Je suis prêt à reconnaitre "Ça a gazé ?" mais en tant que faisant partie de la langue vulgaire ; cependant "T'as gazé ?", qui est une déformation de l'idée,  je rejetterais comme de la « mauvaise langue vulgaire » ; c'est une forme d'introduction récente qui résulte d'un raisonnement à la « pourvu qu'il y  ait du gaz » et qui légitimise n'importe qui et n'importe quoi avec de nouveaux essais tels que « Y'a eu du gaz ?» « T'as eu le gaz ? » "C'était dans le gaz ? », « Bon gaz ? », …

Comment: "T'as gazé le devoir de maths/physique/français ?" est une expression orale très fréquente dans le milieu scolaire du sud-ouest de la France.

Comment: @hoplageiss Ce n'est pas parce que une section de la population s'est mis dans la tête d'utiliser un certain langage que ce langage soit pour cela sacré; il existe des quantités de vocabulaire ordurier  qu'une certaine partie du monde utilise et qu'une plus grand partie encore connais, mais ce n'est pas pour cela qu'on accorde à ce vocabulaire une valeur particulière. Je ne vois pas pourquoi, lorsque l'on dispose de verbes qui expriment l'idée selon un système bien établi (réussir, s'en (bien) tirer, trouver facile, …) on irais chercher un mot qui n'a rien à voir avec la notion exprimée.

Comment: *Ça a gazé* n'a rien de vulgaire. C'est à rapprocher de l'expression *mettre les gaz* pour accélérer en voiture. Même si j'admets que le gaz en question est polluant.

Comment: @Damien Je sais, le TLFi parle de langage familier mais je ne considère pas ce verbe comme étant de la langue standard, de la langue pure, ainsi que beaucoup d'autres d'ailleurs qui sont considérés par les dictionnaires comme n'étant que familiers. J'aurai personnellement toujours une répugnance insurmontable à les utiliser et ne les utiliserai jamais.

Answer (score 1):

On entend couramment l'expression "ça a été ?" dans une autre circonstance, lorsque, à la fin du repas dans un restaurant, l'aubergiste s'enquiert de votre appréciation de sa cuisine. Bien entendu, dans un restaurant assez coûteux, le maître d'hôtel fera en général un effort sémantique supplémentaire (et tarifé dans la note) en vous demandant "ça vous a plu ?" Plus cher encore et vous aurez droit à une phrase plus ampoulée du type "Avez-vous apprécié notre cuisine ?" d'où le "ça" est salutairement expurgé.

Comment: La politesse, la sémantique ou la familiarité ne sont pas forcément liée au prix...

Comment: Certes en toute généralité. Néanmoins, on peut constater expérimentalement que dans aucun restaurant coûteux, vous n'entendrez l'horrible "ça a été", consolation assez maigre j'en conviens.